# Replace all column values with the values ? and n.a with NaN

Tags: pandas, nan

In dataframe, how to replace all column values with the values ? and n.a with NaN?
I tried

`df.fillna(0),inplace=True`

but '?' didn't replace.

Answer (score 1):

To replace all non-NaN values, you can try

```
df = df.where(~df.notna(), "?")
```

and to replace all NaN values,

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC try with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, "?"],
                   ['n.a', 5, 6],
                   [7, '?', 9]],
                  columns=list('ABC'))

df = df.replace({'?': np.NaN, 'n.a': np.NaN})
```

`df` before replace:

```
     A  B  C
0    1  2  ?
1  n.a  5  6
2    7  ?  9
```

`df` after replace:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  NaN  5.0  6.0
2  7.0  NaN  9.0
```